# Attempting to get string value from Response Header in Angular HTTP and map to local storage

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-httpclient

I'm attempting to get a Bearer token that is coming from a .NET Core API that is sent in the 'Authorization' header of a response. The response itself is a 200 OK response that works in Postman and returns 'Some Value' as the response. I've removed the URLs of the API for security reasons, but that's how the response and headers look in Postman

[image: Response in Postman]

[image: Headers in postman]

To attempt to get this value in Angular (latest stable version which I believe is 9) I'm using a service to intercept the pipe and map the response to a local session variable.

Service in angular:

```js
createVisitor() {
  // Create the visitor to send to API
  // TODO: Capture the params of the URL and not the full URL
  this.visitor = {
    BrandCode: 'honey',
    QueryString: 'example=qstring'
  };

  // Set Token as Session & Return a Success/Fail
  return this.http.post(this.api + this.controller + 'createvisitor', this.visitor).pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'));
      const visitor = response.headers.get('Authorization');
      if (visitor) {
        localStorage.setItem('visitor', visitor.Value);
        this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(visitor.Value);
      } else {
        console.log('No Visitor');
      }
    })
  );
}
```

I then subscribe to that response in an Route Guard:

```js
this.visitorService.createVisitor().subscribe(
  (next) => {},
  (error) => {
    console.log("Create Token Error");
  }
);
```

The local storage item is not created and the console shows no error other than the one I created myself (Create Token Error). The request / response all look ok in Google Chrome's network tab too - so no errors there.

Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong or missing there that would cause the error?

Comment: are you using localhost?

Comment: looks like something is erroring in your `createVisitor()` service. That's why you're getting the error when you subscribe to it.

Comment: I'm using localhost for the angular app but the API is live

Comment: Yeah I thought the error was in the createVisitor() method - but I'm not sure what the error is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .pipe() to retrieve response headers in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994231/using-pipe-to-retrieve-response-headers-in-angular)